# Alternating Pos. & Neg. in Geometric Series using For Loop

Tags: c, for-loop, series

I've been asked to create this for loop for my C Programming class but I do not know how to alternate the positive and negative values. Thank you in advance!

sum2=1-x+x^2-x^3+⋯+/-x^n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: consider the expression as sum of (-1*x)^i, with i = 1, 2, 3, ..., n.
If n is even then (-1*x)^i is positive, if odd then negative.